# Can't position image at top of scrollview

Tags: css, react-native

For some reason my image is only in the center of the scrollview, with an equal amount of blank space above and below it. I have tried using bottom, top, justifyContent, alignItems, position, etc. Nothing is working.

```
import React from 'react';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview'
import { ScrollView, Image, View, StyleSheet, Dimensions } from 'react-native';


const StandardizationScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
    return (
        <ScrollView automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false} contentContainerStyle={{justifyContent: "flex-start"}} style={styles.scrollview}>
            <Image style={styles.image} source={require('../assets/standardization/3982243bbc574ccbad697528ff26f605-52.png')}/>
        </ScrollView>
    )
}

const win = Dimensions.get('window');

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    image: {
        width: win.width,
        resizeMode: 'contain',
        alignSelf: 'flex-start'
    },

    scrollview: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: "white",
        alignItems="center"
    }
})

export default StandardizationScreen;
```

Comment: It also does the same with multiple images (image below it creates space above and below

Comment: Do you know if scrollview is display: flex? maybe you are missing that

Comment: alignItems="center" using "=" is not right here

Comment: @lissettdm are display: flex and flex: 1 not the same thing?

Comment: They have different purposes, see https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/